# ExtJs 5 - catch keydown event of Ext.ux.IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, listener, extjs5

In my **ExtJs 5** application I use an **Ext.ux.IFrame**-component to displays a news html document from the intranet.
When I press backspace or alt + left/right, the history navigation of the browser is triggered and the application loads new.

To prevent these behaviour outside of the iframe, I attached a keydown listener to the document

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var documentObj = Ext.getDoc();
    documentObj.on('keydown', globalKeyDown);
});
```

In the callback I stop these events

```
globalKeyDown: function (event, targetDomEle) {
    var eventKey = event.getKey();

    switch (eventKey) {
        case event.BACKSPACE:
            if ((!/^input$/i.test(targetDomEle.tagName) &&
                    !/^textarea$/i.test(targetDomEle.tagName)) ||
                    targetDomEle.disabled || targetDomEle.readOnly) {
                event.stopEvent();
            }
            break;
        case event.LEFT:
        case event.RIGHT:
            if (event.altKey) {
                event.stopEvent();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

But when I try to do the same for the iframe the method to listen for it of the ExtJs framework is not working as expected.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Test',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.IFrame'],
    launch : function() {

        var info = new Ext.Component({
            renderTo: document.body,
            html: 'above the iframe',
            width: 350,
            padding: '0 0 20 0',
            margin: '0 0 1 0',
            style: { border: 'solid 1px blue' },
        });

        var iframe = Ext.create('Ext.ux.IFrame',{
            style: { border: 'solid 1px red' },
            width: 350,
            height: 350,
            renderTo: document.body
        });

        var iframeDoc  = iframe.getDoc();
        var iframeDocEl = Ext.get(iframeDoc);

        iframeDocEl.on('keydown', function(){
            console.log('iframeDoc.on callback'); // <-- never executed
        });

        iframeDoc.onkeyup = function(){
            console.log('onkeyup callback') // <-- works just fine
        };
    }
});
```

Why is `iframeDocEl.on('keydown', ...` not working for this case?
The `iframeDoc.onkeyup` method is just a workaround, because in the callback I want to use the framework event object to be cross browser compatible (IE8+).

Thank you for every suggestions.

The fiddle can be found at [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ftf).

Answer (score 1):

The [Ext.ux.Iframe](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame) source doesn't have events that are fired from within the iframe itself. So it doesn't support this feature. There was a [ManagedIframe](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71961) project a while ago which gave alot more features but it was only supported in ExtJS 3.

It might be worth having a search on the Sencha Forums to see if anyone has attempted to update this extension to be compatible with ExtJS 5.